# Android: ImageButton causes crash upon assigning it a listener

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

So, basically, I have an ImageButton called `boutonPortail`, and another called `logo`. Initializing `boutonPortail` works fine, but when I assign it its listener with `boutonPortail.setOnClickListener(boutonPortailListener);` the app crashes, and I don't know why at all. It's not a problem with the listener since when I assign it to `logo` it works just fine. I doubt it is a problem with the XML since I copy/pasted the code of `logo`.

My app prompts for a password, and if the password is correct it switches to another view with the `logo` and the `boutonPortail`. Note that the password prompt view also has the `logo`.

Is the problem that `boutonPortail` is not on the main view? I tried assigning the listener after switching views, but it still crashes.

EDIT: After putting the button in the main view, the problem is definitely that the button is not in the main view, when I put it in the main view it works fine. Why does it crashes though?

Also, for some reason I can't manage to change the image of the button with `boutonPortail.setImageResource(R.drawable.boutonfermer);`. (this doesn't happen when it is in the main view)

onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    logo = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.logo);
    boutonPortail = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.boutonPortail);
    codeEntered = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.codeEntered);
    codeSurNotice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.codeSurNotice);

    //attribute all listeners
    logo.setOnClickListener(boutonPortailListener);
    codeEntered.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    codeEntered.setOnKeyListener(codeEnteredListener);
```

Method to change view:

```
void codeCorrect() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_readytopress);
    boutonPortail.setOnClickListener(boutonPortailListener); //this line crashes the app, even if put in the onCreate
}
```

Listener:

```
private OnClickListener boutonPortailListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boutonState++;
        if(boutonState>=4)
            boutonState=0;
        boutonPortail.setImageResource(R.drawable.boutonfermer);

    }
};
```

XML:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/boutonPortail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="40dip"
    android:src="@drawable/boutonouvrir"
    android:background="#00000000"
    style="#00000000"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

Here's my full code if you want to test it (note that you'll have to call the `codeCorrect()` method manually since you don't have access to the bluetooth device I use):

`MainActivity.java` http://pastebin.com/ZXDahPZ6
`activity_main.xml` http://pastebin.com/f14cVBKj
`activity_readytopress.xml` http://pastebin.com/0iZm91eq
`boutonouvrir.png` http://puu.sh/mLGeU.png
`ouvertureencours.png` http://puu.sh/mLGfI.png
`boutonfermer.png` http://puu.sh/mLGe5.png
`fermetureencours.png` http://puu.sh/mLGgW.png

Thanks :)

Comment: Also, just post relevant code here, don't have links.

Comment: I don't have access to the stack trace since I test it on my phone :/ also for the relevant code I don't know what to put other than the code to initialize and the listener, but I've updated.

Comment: You can get to the stack trace on your phone.  Hook it up to Android Monitor and you can see the logcat.

Comment: I can't install drivers, for some reason they won't work so adb won't recognize my device.

Comment: Have you just tried a USB device driver?  What OS are you developing on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What do you mean by USB device driver? And I'm using windows 7, but all drivers I've downloaded have done nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a button with the id `boutonPortail` in `activity_main.xml`

It is crashing with a Null Pointer Exception. 
You cannot add a listener to a null object.

Here is your relevant code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // On récupère toutes les vues dont on a besoin
    logo = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.logo);
    boutonPortail = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.boutonPortail);
```

So you call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`  and then you call `findViewById(R.id.boutonPortail)`

The `findContentView()` will return null, because `acitivty_main.xml` does not have a view ID of that value. So now `boutonPortail` is null.

Then you call `boutonPortail.setOnClickListener(boutonPortailListener)` which will crash with a Null Pointer Exception because `boutonPortail` is null

Comment: Yeah, but I have it in activity_readytopress.xml. If I add it in activity_main.xml, it would show in this view, which I don't want.

Comment: @Zezombye: you set visibility of the button to gone ,then when needed set the same to visible

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll do that then, just setting the field to invisible and the button to visible instead of changing view. Still, it's strange that it crashes. Thanks :)